# Why does file.exists() always return true if I don't throw FileNotFoundExcetion in the first place

Tags: java, file-exists

```
public class Main {

final private static int MAX_RECORD_NUMBER = 20;
final private static int RECORD_LENGTH = 71;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the file location and name.");
    String filepath = input.next();
    File file = new File(filepath); 

    boolean isExisted = file.exists(); // Problem exists here if I delete FileNotFoundException

    RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

    if (!isExisted) {
        String dummy = "Empty record                                                           ";
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RECORD_NUMBER; i++) {
            store.writeUTF(dummy);
        }
    }
```

I am stuck at a minor glitch here. The file.exists() methods will **always return true** (even the file was really not there) if I didn't throw FileNotFoundException. In this case, if I don't throw FileNotFoundException at the head of the main method, it's unable to writeUTF to that file. This must be a dumb question but I just want to know what's the mechanism behind this. API doesn't help me neither. I really appreciate anyone that could explain to me.

Edit: Sorry, I was unclear before. What I really wanted to ask is why .exists() method always returns true instead of false or other unexpected errors?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a checked exception ?

Comment: @Dici Yes. So it's all about checked exception? I thought if I didn't throw checked exception, the eclipse won't let me pass. But it didn't show any error when I was coding.

Comment: The title of your question needs to be reworded. Remember every question you write is for people in the future (as well as you).

Comment: Your code could not compile without the `throws` clause, but your question seems to tell me you are a bit unclear on these notions

Comment: @Dici The thing is this can compile without FileNotFoundException, but cannot without IOException. Did the IOException dominate the checked exception so it let me compile anyway? Also what I really wanted to ask is why .exists() method always returns true instead of false or other unexpected errors?

Comment: @PhantomPain `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`.

Comment: @Radiodef Ok, so that means the compiler won't inform me if I didn't write `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Yeah Radiodef is right, `throws IOException, FileNotFoundException` is redundant because of this inheritance relationship. It is equivalent to just `throws IOException`

Comment: Then my question becomes why I need `FileNotFoundException` to make `exists()` method work since I've got `IOException` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to realise where this exception is thrown. And the place is this line:

```
RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
```

Take a look at the API of [FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) and you will know it's thrown just as expected, in the RandomAccessFile constructor.

Test your logic without the RandomAccessFile, with the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input the file location and name.");
        String filepath = input.next();
        File file = new File(filepath); 
        if (file.exists()) System.out.println("EXISTS!"); else System.out.println("DOESN'T EXIST!");
    }

}
```

Now the first part of the problem should be clear. The function `file.exists()` works correctly. The flaw in logic comes from the fact, that the RandomAccessFile constructor is able to create the file, but not always. And that's why you need to service the exception. The following is an excerpt from Java 8 API of the constructor:

*FileNotFoundException - if the mode is "r" but the given file object does not denote an existing regular file, or if the mode begins with "rw" but the given file object does not denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or creating the file*

So the other part of your code might look like this:

```
try {
    RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    String dummy = "Empty record                                                           ";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RECORD_NUMBER; i++) {
       store.writeUTF(dummy);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println("File cannot be created!");
}
```

But this wouldn't be enough, regarding the exception servicing, because you use here the `writeUTF(dummy)` function. And this function throws:

*IOException - if an I/O error occurs.* (As the API of RandomAccessFile says.)

Thus, you need to service the IOException. For example appending one more catch clause to the existing one, this one:

```
catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println("Couldn't write to file!");
}
```

Or you might skip the FileNotFoundException, as it is a subclass of IOException and have just one catch clause with IOException. But, as you can see, here it's quite obvious they stand for two different causes.

And so eventually your class looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

final private static int MAX_RECORD_NUMBER = 20;
final private static int RECORD_LENGTH = 71;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input the file location and name.");
        String filepath = input.next();
        File file = new File(filepath); 
        //if (file.exists()) System.out.println("EXISTS!"); else System.out.println("DOESN'T EXIST!");

        try {
            RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            String dummy = "Empty record                                                           ";
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RECORD_NUMBER; i++) {
               store.writeUTF(dummy);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("File cannot be created!");
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Couldn't write to file!");
        }
    }
}
```

Some parts were not needed. Analyse my solution and it should clarify your mistake. Or ask me for more. This answer is a bit lengthy anyhow.

One last note. People in other threads got confused with similar things. You can see links to them on the right. To cut a long story short, use the full path for the file. And for more details, check the links.

Comment: You have clearly spotted the mistake(s) in his logic, but you're not really answering. Don't let him guess the answer, and think about later readers of your answer. I'll upvote when you edit your question :)

Comment: It should be crystal clear now. Or I don't see a part of the question.

Comment: Ok, I see the other part now.

Comment: I get it now, thank you. One thing left, why does it always return true with `IOException` but without `FileNotFoundException`? That's the essential part here :D

Comment: What I mean is that your solution should also propose a fix, not a snippet to demonstrate the bug

Comment: @PhantomPain It does not always return `true`, I don't know on what you are basing this assumption but it's wrong

Comment: OMG, it doesn't...I tried it again and it becomes normal with just `throws IOException` clause. I don't need `FileNotFoundException` at all. Thank you all anyway lol.

Comment: Now it's more or less complete.

Comment: Compile the first class from my answer. It doesn't service any exceptions. Run it, but first make sure if the file exists in fact, or doesn't. And use full paths, as you may get confused by contexts.

Comment: @tomas thanks for the thorough edit. +1, and good journey on Stack Overflow !

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException

This exception will be thrown by [...] when a file with the specified pathname does not exist.
```

So you could surround the

```
RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
```

with a try-catch block like so:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input the file location and name.");
String filepath = input.next();
File file = new File(filepath); 
boolean isExisted = file.exists(); 

try{

    RandomAccessFile store = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

    if (!isExisted) {
        String dummy = "Empty record                                                           ";
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RECORD_NUMBER; i++) {
            store.writeUTF(dummy);
        }
    }
}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println("File not found!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println("Couldn't write to/read file!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This way if something goes wrong (the user inputs a wrong path/the user has no permissions to read/write to the file) you can handle the error instead of your program crashing. For more info on try-catch blocks check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Comment: He does not **need** to catch the exception. He can also propagate it, which he already does

Comment: Of course he could check for existence before opening the file which would replace the catch, but he has no check in place to determine if he has rights to read/write to the file, even if it exists.

Comment: I just mean he can add the exception to the `throws` clause (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: But then he can't handle it properly, his program is just going to crash. Try-catch exists for a *reason*.

Comment: Checked exceptions also exist for a reason :D Sometimes crashing is the right thing to do. I just don't want your answer to give the impression there is only one way to handle a checked exception

Comment: There is never just *one way* to handle something, I hope I didn't imply that this was the *only* solution :)

Comment: Hahaha I don't want to spam this answer anymore but what I mean is that there are special rules with checked exceptions. I'm not talking about code style or design, I'm talking about specific rules of the language that allow two types of handling for checked exception : catching them or propagating them with a `throws` clause

Comment: The downvote might be either because you commented out `printStackTrace()` or because `new File(pathname)` isn't what throws the exception.